# Strange issue with ifstream read()

Tags: c++

I am new to the forum. I have a strange problem. I have a simple code which reads unformatted data from a file using read() function. The code is given below.

```
int main () {
    ifstream meshfile;
    char buf[1000], ch;
    memset(buf, 0, 1000);
    meshfile.open ("sometextfile");
    meshfile.read (buf, 1000);//38+62+(19*47) + 7);
    cout << strlen(buf) << std::endl;
    cout << buf << std::endl;
}
```

The code when run with the sample input file below gives 1006 as length of buf and prints additional characters for buf. Strangely, this happens only when bufsize is 1000 & 1000 characters are read. Changing the bufsize to > 1000 and reading 1000 chars does not produce this error. Could this be a coding problem?

The sample input file is

> fdjgjdskgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggj bvjgdsv dsjkvgds gvdsj gvjdsgvjksdjkfgdsjkgfdsjgfsdjgfjkdsgfkjsdgjfgsdjfgdsjgfsdjgfjsdgfjsgfjsdgfjgsdjfgsdjfgdsjgfsdjgfsdjgfjsdgfjsdgfjsdg
>   fdjgjdskgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggj bvjgdsv dsjkvgds gvdsj gvjdsgvjksdjkfgdsjkgfdsjgfsdjgfjkdsgfkjsdgjfgsdjfgdsjgfsdjgfjsdgfjsgfjsdgfjgsdjfgsdjfgdsjgfsdjgfsdjgfjsdgfjsdgfjsdg
>   fdjgjdskgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggj bvjgdsv dsjkvgds gvdsj gvjdsgvjksdjkfgdsjkgfdsjgfsdjgfjkdsgfkjsdgjfgsdjfgdsjgfsdjgfjsdgfjsgfjsdgfjgsdjfgsdjfgdsjgfsdjgfsdjgfjsdgfjsdgfjsdg
>   fdjgjdskgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggj bvjgdsv dsjkvgds gvdsj gvjdsgvjksdjkfgdsjkgfdsjgfsdjgfjkdsgfkjsdgjfgsdjfgdsjgfsdjgfjsdgfjsgfjsdgfjgsdjfgsdjfgdsjgfsdjgfsdjgfjsdgfjsdgfjsdg
>   fdjgjdskgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggj bvjgdsv dsjkvgds gvdsj gvjdsgvjksdjkfgdsjkgfdsjgfsdjgfjkdsgfkjsdgjfgsdjfgdsjgfsdjgfjsdgfjsgfjsdgfjgsdjfgsdjfgdsjgfsdjgfsdjgfjsdgfjsdgfjsdg
>   fdjgjdskgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggj bvjgdsv dsjkvgds gvdsj gvjdsgvjksdjkfgdsjkgfdsjgfsdjgfjkdsgfkjsdgjfgsdjfgdsjgfsdjgfjsdgfjsgfjsdgfjgsdjfgsdjfgdsjgfsdjgfsdjgfjsdgfjsdgfjsdg

Comment: Your sample input file has 1068 characters... Why don't you just use the std::string class and do std::string str; meshfile >> str;? Surely letting the string class handle memory management is better than you setting an arbitrary buffer size...

Comment: @lightalchemist I want to do a buffered read. The problem is I don't get any error when I read > 1000 or < 1000. Only the particular case of buflength 1000 and reading 1000 characters gives a strange output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is the use of [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen)
It expects a string terminated by `\0`.

`read` doesn't add a `\0` at the end of the buffer, so strlen reads beyond the edge of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Make your buffer 1001 chars long, leaving room for a nul termination. Memset 1001 also. Without that nul terminator, strlen will not work.

Better yet, use <array> and do not use memset. A simple buf[1000] = 0 will do.

Comment: My issue is this problem does not appear for the case char buf[val] and read(buf, val) when val < 1000 and val > 1000

Answer (score 0):

What's read from the file is not a '\0' terminated string but raw data. You should check the return value of stream.gcount() containing the number of bytes actually read into the buffer and use it in subsequent code. [Manual here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/).

```
  size_t size = meshfile.read(buf, sizeof(buf)/sizeof(*buf)).gcount();
  std::cout << size << std::endl;
```

Comment: gcount gives correct output which is 1000. My issue is this problem does not appear for buf[val] and read(buf, val) when val <1000 and val > 1000

Comment: @user1802229 - your problem is that you implicitly rely on the fact that the N+1-th character of the buffer will be '\0' after reading N characters. It is not the case. In your code, where you write 1000 zeros to the buffer before reading data into it the code "works" for reads shorter or equal to 999 bytes, obviously, because of these 1000 zeros. Once you read 1000 bytes the 1000+1-th byte is beyond the allocated buffer and contains random garbage from the stack.

Comment: If this is the case then declaring char buf[999] and read(buf, 999) should also give the same error which does not occur.

Comment: try adding "{char dummy[1000]=1; std::fill_n(dummy, 100, 'x'); }" just before declaring your 999 bytes long buffer and check what happens.

Comment: @bobah- I don't think it is because of '\0'. char buf[buflen] is supposed to store buflen no of characters. Small sequences are recognized by the terminating null character. What I am doing in my code should be perfectly okay. I read 1000 unformatted characters as input. So when I output I should get all the 1000 characters. When I do this I am printing 1006 characters which doesn't make any sense

Comment: @bobah- This code snippet is perfectly okay for some reason    int main () {
  ifstream meshfile;
  char buf[5]={'S','u','m','a','n'};

  std::cout << buf << std::endl;
  std::cout << strlen(buf) << std::endl;

}

Comment: Run your code under valgrind and you will see how "perfectly okay" it is. strlen(buffer) performs out of boundaries read (aka ABR memory error).

Comment: Found out the issue. I can actually do this char buf[len] & read(buf,len). But somehow std::cout<<buf<<std::endl needs a \0 at the end. :) So the output with which I had issues is now okay. Many thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

I think what the guys here and I mean is:

1)read(..) does not add the null terminator.

2)You initialized your buffer to 0 using memset. When you read < 1000 characters, the array elements that comes after the last character read in are all still 0 (effectively null, because they were initialized to that value) hence even if read(..) did not add the null terminator, things did not break. This is why Jive Dadson asks you to resize your buffer to 1001 char and initialize your array to 0, so that even if you read in 1000 characters, the 1001th character is still 0 and will act as the null terminator.

But this is actually a bug. Consider what happens when you read in the last line which has < BUF_SIZE? Hence it is better to check for the number of characters read in at each turn as suggested by some of the posters.

3)When you read > 1000 characters, did you changed to a larger buffer and did you initialize your buffer to '0' for this larger buffer? If so naturally you won't have a problem as the situation will be the same as above. If not, I'm curious how you can read > 1000 characters into a 1000 char buffer.

4)Basically your current method of reading data is unreliable. You should resize your buffer to have 1 more element than the max you intend to read. After each read, you should get the number of characters actually read in and set the null terminator if you intend to pass the buf as a string and perform operations such as copy, printf etc.

Comment: Found out the issue. I can actually do this char buf[len] & read(buf,len). But somehow std::cout<<buf<<std::endl needs a \0 at the end. :) So the output with which I had issues is now okay. Also I don't need a \0 to convert to a string !! Many thanks for your comments